Formula regarding Big-Oh (and a bit math)
I want to show that $O(max\{f(n),g(n)\}) = O(f(n)+g(n))$, and wonder if this argument works out!
Let $f(n) = max\{f(n),g(n)\}$. If otherwise we could just switch cases. $f(n) \leq ch(n)$ for some function $h$ and an constant $c$. But $g(n)\leq f(n)$, so $g(n) \leq ch(n)$. Hence:
$$max\{f(n),g(n)\} = f(n) \in O(h(n))$$
$$f(n)+g(n) \in O(h(n))+O(h(n)) = O(h(n)+h(n)) = O(2h(n)) = O(h(n))$$
I'm new to this field, and not exactly an expert in math either, so help/input is greatly appreciated!

Note that $\max(f, g) \leq f+g$, thus $\max(f,g) \in O(f+g)$. For the other direction, observe that $f+g \leq 2\max(f,g)$ for $f, g\geq 0$, therefore $f+g \in O(\max(f,g))$. Altogether this implies the desired property.
The issue with your argument is that $\max(f,g)$ is not necessarily either $f$ or $g$; consider $\max(\sin(x), \cos(x))$, for instance.

Indeed! It’s not mathematically valid, although the algorithms usuallt grows as input grow.
